# Client_side_validations gem not working in rails 3.2.13

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, client-side-validation

I've spent quite a while trying to get **client_side_validations** gem to work, but no text is showing up and **no script tags are being injected after the forms**. I have tried it with both the standard form generated by Rails and a Devise form. I have made sure to include the rails.validations.js file and uncomment the block within the initialiser supplied with the gem.

Here is my code:

**client_side_validations.rb**

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

**JS include**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/javascript/rails.validations.js" %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'client_side_validations'
```

**Standard rails form**

```
<%= form_for(@report, :validate => true) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :url, :value => "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}#{request.fullpath}" %>

<%= f.label :elements %>
<%= f.text_field :elements %>

<%= f.label :comments %>
<%= f.text_area :comments %>

<%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn' %>
```

**Devise form**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.label "First name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.label "Last name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.label :privacy_policy, :class => 'checkbox' do %>
  <%= f.check_box :privacy_policy %>I agree to the <%= link_to "Privacy policy", privacy_path %><% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

I am literally at a loss as to what I can do next. Would I need to reference a different version of the gem? How can I check to see if the gem is actually functioning?

I am currently using **Rails 3.2.13**

I am not getting any errors in the javascript console.

If you would like to look at the related files, let me know.

**Any pointers would be very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'client_side_validations`, :github => 'bcardarella/client_side_validations', :branch => '3-2-stable'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Turns out I needed to restart the rails server too. You're a star!

Comment: I'm now getting the problem of the client side validations only triggering when I submit the form with devise. They do not trigger when I tab through them, any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use Devise so I'm not sure what you're running into